# Add and remove items from array: nodes keep high but no Detached dom found

Tags: angular, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I'm analyzing my angular 5 app (and PrimeNg). 
I'm trying to get if I've some potentially memory leak after 'adding' some objects to an array and 'removing' them (so at the end my view is identical as the page was just loaded, I'm expecting to see a reduction of JS Heap and DOM elements after a run of the GC).

I've recorded this 'adding' and 'removing' operations, it seems that DOM elements keep to be high, but I don't have any Detached DOM elements... Isn't that weird? I've no any explanation for that.

Do you ? :) Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like chrome 66 have renamed/removed the Detached dom tree elements

Comment: any news? am I the only one with this issue ?